# My embedded Javascript is not displaying on an html canvas and I would like to know the structure for this in the future

Tags: javascript, html, css

I apologize as I am a relative beginner to programming, especially for the web. I am currently try to utilize the videos from [code player](http://thecodeplayer.com/) but the website does not show how each file is linked together through the html. The below is the current structure of the html file. I would like to know how this needs to be changed to get the javascript to display in the canvas. (The style sheet works correctly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GaugeStyling.css">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gaugescripts.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am too a relative beginner but for a start you don't need the type in the script anymore and you put the script in the head section, which you don't seem to have.

In your gaugescripts.js, i presume you have a line such as:

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");

if you so that how you connect the two after the i'd need to see the script to see where your problem lies.

good luck

Comment: You can put script tags anywhere, not just in the header. It merely changes when they are loaded.